# How to join all text of a column while changing the format of the data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dates in a column that I join together and it gives me these values:

```
44670, 44691, 44691
```

I want the dates to be formatted properly like this

```
April- 19, May- 10, May- 10
```

**Problem is I want to join and format any values in that column but it is also taking all the zeroes in the column and giving me an error for being too long.**

So I have tried doing this but it seems slow or sometimes doesnt work:

```
=TEXTJOIN("
", TRUE, TEXT(IF(Sheet2!E:E>0,Sheet2!E:E,""), "mmm- dd"))
```

**How would you go on about doing this?**

Comment: All Column or a cell?

Comment: All rows of a column, or at least a minimum of 15 rows of a column

Comment: Yeah so the numbers that are like this 44670, 44691, 44691 is excels way for formatting dates. When I convert the cell into a date it properly gives me the date but when I am referencing it it returns as this 44670, 44691, 44691. Therefore I need to format that into an actual readable date.

Comment: Sir, if I have understood correctly you may need to use this, `=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, TEXT(FILTER(Sheet2!E:E,Sheet2!E:E<>""), "mmm- dd;;"))` instead of using `IF()` use `FILTER()` function it ignores the blanks and also keeps the required formatting as needed because of `TEXT()` Function

Comment: Sir, using `IF()` function it becomes slow, also you are using the whole column here where there are blanks, which is not required you can use absolute references or use the `FILTER()` Function to exclude the blanks

Comment: Sir, could you confirm whether it is working properly or not?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: Since it has worked shall I go ahead and post it as an answer then?

Comment: Yeah go ahead. No problem

Comment: TEXTJOIN has it's own built in filter on empty values (second parameter `TRUE` or `1`). Then the following would work as well `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,TEXT(E:E,"mmm- dd;;"))`

Comment: @P.b Sir, it does work, but it takes time to process which I found out now, while using a `FILTER()` Function it speeds up the efficiency.

Comment: Good to know. It would be less slow if the range is narrowed down (not referencing the whole column)

Comment: @P.b Sir, earlier i tried the way as you have mentioned but it wasn't working and was taking a time, you know that offending 4threads, while when i used the `FILTER()` it was just in seconds. May be there some better option to use it with `LAMBDA()` as well

Comment: I'm doing this on the app version of Excel on my phone and it takes less then 2 seconds to calculate. But FILTER is almost instant.

Comment: @P.b Sir, aha right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I have commented above and its a working solution for OP, sharing it here as an ***Answer*** as well,

[image]

• Formula used in cell **C1**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, TEXT(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""), "mmm- dd;;"))
```

---

Instead of using `IF()` use `FILTER()` function it ignores the blanks and also keeps the required formatting as needed because of `TEXT()` Function

Formula as per OP's Worksheet

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, TEXT(FILTER(Sheet2!E:E,Sheet2!E:E<>""), "mmm- dd;;"))
```